Determining status of an untrusted Git repo
I'd like to determine whether a repo is modified and which patches it contains (so essentially I'd like to run git log, git status and git diff). However, the repo is untrusted. Which commands are safe?
I think I'd need to at least pass --no-textconv and --no-ext-diff to git diff. Is this enough?
Will git status and git log (without -p) call user-defined commands?

Define "untrusted". What are your concerns? What do you want to protect and against what?

@Alejandro Threat model: the repository contains unknown (potentially hostile) content. If an attacker (who created the repo) managed to run arbitrary commands in the context of the user inspecting the repo, that would be bad.
